# SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE deprecated starting android 30

Tags: android

I used `SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE` in order to show all content when keyboard pops up.
Following documentation, I added new code pieces:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
    requireActivity().window.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(false)
}
```

and

```
binding.constraintLayoutRoot.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener { _, windowInsets ->
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        val insets = windowInsets.getInsets(WindowInsets.Type.ime() or WindowInsets.Type.systemGestures())
        insets
    }

    windowInsets
}
```

For some reason, view does not resize based on the fact if the keyboard appears or not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Can you try doing the following, I think we have to manually add the padding for the keyboard now.

```kotlin
binding.root.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener { _, windowInsets ->
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        val imeHeight = windowInsets.getInsets(WindowInsets.Type.ime()).bottom
        binding.root.setPadding(0, 0, 0, imeHeight)
        val insets = windowInsets.getInsets(WindowInsets.Type.ime() or WindowInsets.Type.systemGestures())
        insets
    }

    windowInsets
}
```

Comment: What happens to versions below SDK 30?

Comment: You have already added a check for the SDK right? SO I am guessing it would work normally?

Answer (score 19):

As per google developers from Android API 30, they have deprecated it and provided us with a workaround **setDecorFitsSystemWindows**. But this will not work below Android 30 for below 30 you have to use the same method as before.

**How it works:**
When **setDecorFitsSystemWindows** is **true**
the framework will check **SYSTEM_UI_LAYOUT_FLAGS** as well the WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE flag and fits content according to these flags.

But when it is set to **False** the framework will not fit the content view to the insets and will check your WindowInsets to set the content view.

First, you have to define your windowsInsets which it can use

```
binding.root.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener { _, windowInsets ->
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
            val imeHeight = windowInsets.getInsets(WindowInsets.Type.ime()).bottom
            binding.root.setPadding(0, 0, 0, imeHeight)
        }
        windowInsets
    }
```

and then when you want your screen to use **ADUST_RESIZE** set false

```
setDecorFitsSystemWindows(false)
```

When you want back to normal set true

```
setDecorFitsSystemWindows(true)
```

Managing for API 30 above and below use conditions

```
var shouldResize = false // false will resize
    binding.button.setOnClickListener {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
            window.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(shouldResize)
            shouldResize = shouldResize.not()
        } else {
            if (shouldResize.not()) {
                window.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE)
            } else {
                window.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN)
            }
        }
    }
```

**Reference link:**

> [Android SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams#SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE)
>
> [Android setDecorFitsSystemWindows](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window#setDecorFitsSystemWindows(boolean))

Comment: What is the point of updating `shouldResize` to `shouldResize = shouldResize.not()`?

Comment: oh great. I have an app that needs to adjust one way when entering text into one EditText, and adjust a different way when entering text into a different EditText, and now I will need spaghetti code to sort them both out...

Answer (score 5):

The simplest solution is to add the following to `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```xml
<activity
    android:name=".MyActivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
```

Answer (score 5):

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(requireDialog().window?.decorView!!) { _, insets ->
            val imeHeight = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.ime()).bottom
            val navigationBarHeight =
                insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.navigationBars()).bottom
            viewBinding.root.setPadding(0, 0, 0, imeHeight - navigationBarHeight)
            insets
        }
    } else {
        @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
        requireDialog().window?.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE)
    }
```

For **BottomSheetDialogFragment()**, please like this answer if you also facing the same issue.
Works perfect for me, tested.
By the way, paste above code in **onViewCreated()**

Answer (score 4):

In case you are using `BottomSheetDialogFragment`, be sure to call methods on `requireDialog().window` instead of `requireActivity().window`

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
  requireDialog().window?.let { WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(it, false) }
} else {
  @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
  requireDialog().window?.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could not get any of these to work with dialogs.
For activities Tatsuya Fujisaki's solution works fine, but for dialogs to resize the layout needs to match the parent

```
val window = this.window
window?.setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
```