# SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE is deprecated and the fix is not woking as expected

Tags: android, kotlin, input, toolbar

SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE  is deprecated and followed below link to fix: [SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE deprecated starting android 30](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68003131/soft-input-adjust-resize-deprecated-starting-android-30)

But facing issues in the tool bar, can anyone faced same issue and it was fixed please respond.